# Error parsing JSON: {'Account_ID': None} when loading to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a csv file I'm trying to load to Snowflake that has a column 'custom_fields', everything in this column is a dictionary, but one row had a None key, for example `{'Account_ID': None}` which threw the error

`Error parsing JSON: {'Account_ID': None}`

I have the format set up like below, where I tried also adding 'None' within `null_if`

```
@property
def fileformat_opts(self):
    return {
        'type': 'csv',
        'skip_header': 1,
        'field_delimiter': ',',
        'field_optionally_enclosed_by': '"',
        'escape_unenclosed_field': None,
        'date_format': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'record_delimiter': '\n',
        'null_if': ('NULL', '', ' ', 'NULL', '//N', 'None'),
        'empty_field_as_null': True,
        'error_on_column_count_mismatch': False,
        'timestamp_format': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to parse this:

```
{"Account_ID": None}
```

None is not a valid JSON value. You can check your JSON string using any online validator. For example:

https://jsonlint.com/

As a solution, you can write **null** instead of **None** to your CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You need dumps dictionary to json, e.g. in python `json.dumps(dict)`, then only can load to Snowflake as `object` or `variant`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).